# VBA: How to test if Outlook is Working Offline, and if not then put it in Offline Mode

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

Before emails are sent out using VBA in Excel I place Outlook in offline mode so that the emails do not sent and I can check them.

The problem with this is that I would have to make sure Outlook is in offline mode every time.

I have found the following code to put Outlook in offline mode:

```
Outlook.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.FindControl(, 5613).Execute
```

But the problem with this is that if Outlook in Offline mode it will take it out of Offline mode, so what I want is to test whether Outlook is in Offline mode, and if not run the code.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Why not simply `.Save` the `MailMessages` as draft?

Comment: That wouldn't be useful because it would be quicker if the emails went into the outbox so that all that needs doing to send them is to turn the working offline mode off

Answer (score 0):

To check for offline-mode on an Exchange connected Outlook client, you can check the `ExchangeConnectionMode` property of the `Session` object.

For example, you can do the following:

```
Dim oNS As NameSpace
Set oNS = Application.Session

If oNS.ExchangeConnectionMode = olCachedOffline Or _
   oNS.ExchangeConnectionMode = olOffline Then
   ... Work, work! ...
End If
```